# css3 webkit keuframe rules in epub

Tags: css, webkit, epub3

I am having an issue about validating CSS3 Animation with EpubCheck 3.0.I receive the following warning messages.can you help me by providing some links.

WARNING: SimpleSample3_css3-keyframes.epub/EPUB/Style/style.css(5): Token '0%' not allowed here
WARNING: SimpleSample3_css3-keyframes.epub/EPUB/Style/style.css(6): Token '50%' not allowed here
WARNING: SimpleSample3_css3-keyframes.epub/EPUB/Style/style.css(7): Token '100%' not allowed here

Comment: Can you maybe provide your style.css file, or at least the concerned lines? Would be helpful to figure out...

Comment: please find my css below#elephant_head{
-webkit-animation:elephant_head 0.5s infinite linear alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes elephant_head {
0%{top: 631px; left:629px;}
 50%{top: 629px; left:629px;}
 100%{top: 631px; left: 629px;}
 }

Comment: can you please help me to fix the above issue?i am inthe endppoint to complete my epub

Comment: I'm trying to understand what's happening there... at a first glance your code looks correct. Did you try separating the % and the { character with a space? (although I don't see any reason it shouldn't work without the space). Maybe also try to have a different name for the ID (`#elephant_head`) and the animation (@...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have tried your suggestions but still i get the same warning message

Comment: See my answer below, it is a bug in EPubCheck.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is a known bug of EPubCheck 3.0. See this bug report: http://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/issues/detail?id=241. Try to update to the latest revision (bug was corrected in r449, released on March 26st, 2013).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.can you send me the link to the latest version .

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the latest revision has no downloadable package, you will have to download the Java sources by SVN (command: `svn checkout http://epubcheck.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ epubcheck-read-only`) and compile them (which requires Apache Maven, see the README.txt file included in the source).